# Why won't this Spark sample code load in spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The example code below is from the book Advanced Analytics with Spark.  When I load it into spark-shell (version 1.4.1) it gives the following error, indicating that it can't find StatCounter:

```
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
<console>:9: error: not found: type StatCounter
        val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
                   ^
<console>:9: error: not found: type StatCounter
        val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
                                     ^
<console>:23: error: not found: type NAStatCounter
        def apply(x: Double) = new NAStatCounter().add(x)
```

If I just do the following in spark-shell there is no problem:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter

scala> val statsCounter: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
statsCounter: org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter = (count: 0, mean: 0.000000, stdev: NaN, max: -Infinity, min: Infinity)
```

The problem seems to be with the :load command in spark-shell.

Here's the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
class NAStatCounter extends Serializable {
    val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
    var missing: Long = 0

    def add(x: Double): NAStatCounter = {
        if (java.lang.Double.isNaN(x)) {
            missing += 1
        } else {
        stats.merge(x)
        }
        this
    }

    def merge(other: NAStatCounter): NAStatCounter = {
        stats.merge(other.stats)
        missing += other.missing
        this
    }

    override def toString = {
        "stats: " + stats.toString + " NaN: " + missing
    }
}

object NAStatCounter extends Serializable {
    def apply(x: Double) = new NAStatCounter().add(x)
}
```

Comment: Is that library in the class path? Can you tell us the location of that library and print out your lib path?

Comment: I found that I have to fully qualify StatCounter when declaring it, even though I imported it:  `val stats: org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter = new org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter()`

Comment: It's in the classpath by default.  The two line example from the spark-shell in the middle code block above shows that.  When I load a file is when the problem occurs.

Comment: Other than having the wrong scala version, which has caused problems from time to time, I can't say whats causing it

Comment: When I copy and save that code to a file, I get the following in Spark 1.4.1 shell:

scala> :load /tmp/test.scala
Loading /tmp/test.scala...
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
defined class NAStatCounter
defined module NAStatCounter
warning: previously defined class NAStatCounter is not a companion to object NAStatCounter.
Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.

Answer (score 3):

I have the exactly same problem  with you.  
I solve it as you tried,
CHANGE

```
val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
```

INTO

```
val stats: org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter = new org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter()
```

the reason perhaps is the system don't know the path of  StatCounter

Comment: Please add syntax highlighting to your source code.